Can't write to HID device using Device.Net library
I am trying to communicate with an HID device (STM32) using the Device.Net library. At the moment I have to transmit 256 bytes (including ReportID) from my PC, which represents the device's status request. The device must in turn respond with another 256 bytes. I manage to initialise everything without any problems, the error occurs when I try to send the 256 bytes, telling me:
System.IO.IOException: ‘An error occurred while attempting to write to the device’
This exception was originally generated in the following call stack:
System.IO.Strategies.BufferedFileStreamStrategy.WriteToNonSeekableAsync(System.ReadOnlyMemory<byte>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
Hid.Net.Windows.WindowsHidHandler.WriteReportAsync(byte[], byte, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
Hid.Net.HidDevice.WriteReportAsync(byte[], byte, System.Threading.CancellationToken).

https://github.com/user-attachments/assets/d2109f1b-34aa-4e9a-ad4b-5aa0b381ef8a
Full code
using Device.Net;
using Hid.Net.Windows;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MauiApp_Test_Usb
{
    public class UsbManager
    {
        private static IDevice markDevice;
        private TransferResult readBuffer;
        public async Task InitializeUsbAsync()
        {
            var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create((builder) =>
            {
                _ = builder.AddDebug().SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            });

            // Definisci i device che l'app deve cercare
            var hidFactory = new FilterDeviceDefinition(vendorId: 0x0483, productId: 0x5750).CreateWindowsHidDeviceFactory(loggerFactory);

            //Get connected device definitions
            var deviceDefinitions = (await hidFactory.GetConnectedDeviceDefinitionsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)).ToList();
            if (deviceDefinitions.Count == 0)
            {
                //No devices were found
                return;
            }

            //Get the device from its definition
            markDevice = await hidFactory.GetDeviceAsync(deviceDefinitions.First()).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await markDevice.InitializeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            MainPage.timer.Start();
        }

        public bool GetIsInitialized()
        {
            return markDevice.IsInitialized;
        }
        public TransferResult GetReadBuffer()
        {
            return readBuffer;
        }

        public async void sendStatus()
        {
            //Create the request buffer
            var buffer = new byte[256];
            buffer[0] = 0x02;
            buffer[1] = 0x01;

            //Write and read the data to the device
            var readBuffer = await markDevice.WriteAndReadAsync(buffer).ConfigureAwait(false); // <-- ERROR HERE
        }
    }
}

System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Messaggio=An error occurred while attempting to write to the device
  Origine=Hid.Net
  Analisi dello stack:
   in Hid.Net.HidDevice.<WriteReportAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
   in Device.Net.DeviceBase.<WriteAndReadAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
   in MauiApp_Test_Usb.UsbManager.<sendStatus>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Users\simonebenincasa\Documents\Progetti visual studio\MauiApp Test Usb\MauiApp Test Usb\usbManager.cs: riga 53

  Questa eccezione è stata generata in origine nello stack di chiamate seguente:
    System.IO.Strategies.BufferedFileStreamStrategy.WriteToNonSeekableAsync(System.ReadOnlyMemory<byte>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    Hid.Net.Windows.WindowsHidHandler.WriteReportAsync(byte[], byte, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    Hid.Net.HidDevice.WriteReportAsync(byte[], byte, System.Threading.CancellationToken)

Eccezione interna 1:
IOException: Parametro non corretto.

Did I miss something?
Thank you in advance for your support
Info

Platform: Windows 11
Device Type: Hid
Version: 4.2.1


Why aren’t you awaiting the call to InitializeAsync?

@Jason You are right, I just fixed it, now I also do an await during initialisation. However, the problem persists

Is there an InnerException?

@canton7 I guess so, it is the internal code of the nuget ‘Device.Net’ package

Huh? Look at the exception's properties. Is the InnerException property null, or does it have a value? There's no need to guess.

@canton7 Sorry, now I understand. The internal exception says that the device has not been initialised (NotInitialisedException: The device has not been initialised), but if I look at the ‘IsInitialised’ property of the device, it comes out as true

Looks like it might be an issue with the Hid.Net library, then? I doubt there's anyone on here who knows its internals well enough to debug your issue. I see you've opened an issue there, but it also looks like the project might be dead. Your next step is probably to debug the Hid.Net code, and see what's going wrong. Good luck!

@canton7 Alright thank you very much!
